# How to replicate, for DR purposes, a Greenplum DB to another data centre?

Tags: greenplum

We are planning for a large Greenplum DB (growing from 10 to 100TB over the first 18 months). Traditional backup and restore tools aren't going to help as we have 24hr RPO/RTOs to deal with.
Is there a way to replicate the DB across to our DR site without resorting to block replication (i.e. place a segment on SAN and mirror)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a number of options to choose:

1. Dual ETL. Replicate input data and run the same ETL on two sites. Synchronize them with backup-restore every week or so
2. Backup-restore. Simple backup-restore can be not that efficient. But if you use DataDomain it can perform deduplication on the block level and store only changed blocks. It can offload the deduplication task to run on the Greenplum cluster (DDBoost). Also in case of replication to remote site it would replicate only changed blocks, which would greatly reduce replication time. In my experience, if clean backup on DD takes 12 hours, subsequent DDBoost backup will take 4 hours + 4 hours to replicate the data
3. Custom solution. I know the case when the data replicatioin to remote site is made as a part of ETL process. For the ETL job you know which tables are changed, they are added to the replication queue and moved to the remote site using external tables. Analysts are working in a special sandbox and their sandbox is replicated with backup-restore daily

At the moment Greenplum does not have built-in WAN replication solution so this is almost all the options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I do some investigation on this. here is my result

```
I.  Using EMC Symmetrix VMAX SAN(Storage Area Network)  Mirror  and SRDF (Symmetrix Remote Data Facility) remote replication software
Please refer to h12079-vnx-replication-technologies-overview-wp.pdf for details
  Preconditions
             1. Having EMC Symmetrix VMAX SAN installed
             2. Having SRDF softeware

  Advantages of 3 different modes
 1. Symmetrix Remote Data Facility / Synchronous (SRDF/S)
            Provides a no data loss solution (Zero RPO). 
            No server resource contention for remote mirroring operation. 
            Can perform restoration of primary site with minimal impact to      application.  Performance on remote site.  Enterprise
    disaster recovery solution.  Supports replicating over IP and Fibre
    Channel protocols. 

    2.  Symmetrix Remote Data Facility / Asynchronous (SRDF/A) Extended-distance data replication that supports longer distances
    than SRDF/S.  SRDF/A does not affect host performance, because host
    activity is decoupled from the remote copy process.  Efficient link
    utilization that results in lower link-bandwidth requirements.
    Facilities to invoke failover and restore operations.  Supports
    replicating over IP and Fibre Channel protocols. 

    3.  Symmetrix Remote Data Facility / Data Mobility (SRDF/DM)

II. Using Backup Tools

Please refer to http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4350/admin_guide/managing/backup.html for details
Parallel Backup 
Parallel backup utility gpcrondump 

Non-parallel backup
It is not recommended. It is used for migrate PostgreSQL databases to GreenPlum databases

Parallel Restore 
Support system with the same configuration and different configuration with the source GreenPlum database configuration

Non-Parallel Restore
pg_restore requires to modified the create statement to add distributed by clause

 
Disadvantages
1.  The backup process locks table, it put an EXCLUSIVE lock on table pg_class. It means that read permission is only allowed in this period. 
2.  After releasing the EXCLUSIVE lock on table pg_clas, it will put an ACCESS SHARE lock on all the tables, it only allows read access during the lock period.


III.    Replay DDL statements 
In PostgreSQL, there is a parameters to log all the sql statements to a file. 
In the data/postgresql.conf, modify log_statement to ‘all’
Write an application to get the DML and DDL statement, and run them in the DR servers.
Advantage
1.  Easy to configure and maintain
2.  No decrease in the performance
Disadvantage
1.  Need additional storage for the statement logging

IV. Parse the wal log of PostgreSQL 
Parse the wal log to extract the DDL statement from the log and then run all the generated DDL statements in the DR GreenPlum
Advantage
1.  Doesn’t impact the source GreenPlum Database
Disadvantage
1.  Write code to parse the wal log
2.  Not easy to parse the log, there are not enough documents about the wal log. 
3.  Don’t know if it is feasible for GreenPlum, as it is one solution for PostgreSQL.
```